# How to run an all-permissions applet?

Tags: java, security, permissions, applet

I made an applet that has to ask `all-permissions` in it's manifest file  (It is getting the computer's mac address). I did everything I know to let the applet run on my browser: (I hosted it in www.biz.nf).

- I self signed it using the command prompt.
- I changed  the java control panel's security setting to medium (the lowest possible)
- I added to the jnlp file : `<security> <all-permissions/> </security>` and I have set the permissions attribute in the manifest file to `all-permissions`.
- I added to the exception site list all the addresses I thought could be useful: `http://www.encrymai.co.nf` , `http://www.encrymai.co.nf/getMac.jar` , `http://www.encrymai.co.nf/getMac.jnlp` , `http://www.encrymai.co.nf/?`

Nothing helps. Whatever I do I get the same security prompt saying "The java security settings have prevented this application from running. You may change this behavior in the Java Control Panel." and in the java console: `basic: exception: The Java security settings have prevented this application from running. You may change this behavior in the Java Control Panel..` , but as I mentioned I did what I can in the java control panel.

edit: I am deploying the applet with a jnlp file.

Comment: `http://www.encrymai.co.nf` is enough in your list of exceptions. Do you deploy it with a jnlp? If yes have you set the security to `all-permissions`? If not have you set the [security level of your applet to `all-permissions`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/applet_deployment.html#SECURITY)?

Comment: Yes I deploy it with jnlp. Yes, I have set the permissions attribute in the manifest file to all-permissions and in the jnlp I added : '<security><all-permissions/></security>'. Still the same error.

Comment: Have you checked the JNLP using JaNeLA?

Comment: Yes. No errors in there.